# Have an alert and redirect after pressing a particular button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form with 3 different buttons on it, I want it so that once the 3rd button is pressed. the user will be redirected to a different page.

Ive tried adding "onsubmit" to the button but nothing happens.

Anyone know a way to do this?

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

Put counter on three of that buttons and all buttons have same method.

your button is :

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
```

might be your onclick function is :

```
<script>
var counter=0;
function myFunction() {
    if(counter == 3){
       // your redirection of page.
        alert("your statment");
        document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
   }else{
      counter ++;      
}
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

onsubmit is method of form not button .

Use click method for button.

```
$(".className or #id of button").on("click",function(){
    window.open ("link of the page","window name","status=1");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The "onsubmit" attribute is primarily for submitting forms. You likely want "onclick".

```js
function myFunction() {
  // Do stuff.
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Third Button!</button>
```

Comment: Nothing happens on click

Comment: In my snippet or when you try to implement my demonstration? Nothing is supposed to happen in the snippet, it's to demonstrate how to fix your problem.

Comment: Yeah i know, I added a similar thing to my code and nothing happened still

Comment: So post your code. We can't help diagnose an issue without seeing it.